# Let $n$ be prime, for which $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is the map $\phi_k$ a group isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, prime-numbers, group-isomorphism

Problem:

Let $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$ We define the following group homomorphism.

$$\phi_k: (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \to (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}), [a] \mapsto [ka]$$

Let $n$ be prime. For which $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is $\phi_k$ a group isomorphism.

Questions:

Right now from what i know is that $\phi_k$ is a homomorphism. So what i need to prove for the group isomorphism, is that $\phi_k$ is either injective or surjective. Though right now i am coming to a little bit of a blockade involving the use of the fact that n is prime. I would require either a comprehensive solution to this relatively probably simple problem. Or some way of helping me get onto the right track of using the properties of n and $\phi_k$.
I thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Hint: by looking at $\phi_k^{-1}(1)$ show that $\phi_k$ is invertible iff $k$ is invertible mod $n$.

Comment: Well, why not start with examples?  Take $n=5$.  What's the answer in that case?

Comment: Well for n = 5, the k has to be either a multiple of 5 or 1 (aka, the identity) for it to work. At least for $\phi_k$ to be surjective. I hope i am correct with the assumption.

Comment: What do you know about invertibility condtions on $Z/nZ$ when $n$ prime ? What does it implies for the condtion on $k$ for $\phi_k$ to be an isomorphism ? In other words in which condition(s) on $k$ can you recover $a$ from $ka$ ?

Comment: Why should you make any assumptions?  Just write it out.  Every integer is a multiple of $1$ so you are saying that every $k$ work, yes?  So $k=0$ works?

Comment: Side note:  I'm not sure you know what the terms you are using mean.  If you know that $\phi_k$ is an "automorphism" then you are done, there is nothing left to prove.  I think you mean to say "homomorphism", but I am not sure.

Comment: Well i meant to probably say homomorphism. Let me edit this.

Comment: I might still have a blockade. I might not really understand what you mean by writing this out. Excuse me for being slow to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a finite set $X$ a function $X\to X$ is injective if and only if it is surjective. So it is enough to check when $\phi_k$ is injective. And for homomorphisms it is enough to check when the kernel is trivial.

So assume that $\phi_k([x])=[0]$ which is if and only if $[kx]=[0]$ which is if and only if $n$ divides $kx$. Now if $gcd(k,n)=1$ then the only possibility is that $n$ divides $x$, i.e. $[x]=[0]$. So we get that when $gcd(k,n)=1$ then $\phi_k$ is an isomorphism.

On the other hand, assume that $g=gcd(k,n)\neq 1$. Put $k=k'g$. Then for $x=n/g$ we get
$$\phi_k([x])=[kx]=[k'g\frac{n}{g}]=[k'n]=[0]$$
Note that when $g\neq 1$ then $1\leq x <n$ and thus $[x]\neq[0]$. Therefore $\phi_k$ is not an isomorphism.

All in all we get: $\phi_k$ is an isomorphism if and only if $gcd(k,n)=1$. Which for prime $n$ means: if and only if $n$ does not divide $k$.

Comment: Could you explain to me why $[kx] = [0]$ if n divides kx ? I would like to know where to get there. In a little bit more detail. I would appreciate that.

Comment: @MarkLauer $[x]=[y]$ is a simpler way of writing $x+n\mathbb{Z}=y+n\mathbb{Z}$ which is if and only if $x-y+n\mathbb{Z}=n\mathbb{Z}$ which is if and only if $x-y\in n\mathbb{Z}$ which is if and only if $n$ divides $x-y$.